# How to highlight two excel cells contain multiple words in each cell

Tags: excel

this may be a bit difficult to explain but i will use the example below

[image]

as you can see, the excel sheet has two columns (C and F) I was able to use conditional formatting to highlight the duplicate cells with the green color. I would like to know how to also two different cells that contain multiple words with at-least one word in each cell being the same, as you can see the cells with the yellow color. thanks

Comment: Please take a moment to learn what this site is about (i.e. programming), read the FAQ about how to ask a question. Then post the code you have come up with so far and explain where you are stuck. If your question is not about programming, you're on the wrong site. Post on SuperUser.com, not here.

Comment: This can be achieved very easily. But as @teylyn said, we will not write the code for you. You have to make an effort. We can then help and guide you once you post your code

Answer (score -1):

You can use a UDF below to compare the values

```
Public Function comparecells(cell1 As String, cell2 As String) As Boolean

'store words of each cells in two diffrent arrays

    array1 = Split(cell1, " ")
    array2 = Split(cell2, " ")

    'reset the function value
    comparecells = False

    'check each word from one array against the other
    For Each Value1 In array1
        For Each Value2 In array2
            If Value1 = Value2 Then
                'If it finds any match set function return value to true and exit
                comparecells = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next Value2
    Next Value1

End Function
```

Comment: This site is not a free scripting service. By answering such a bad question you are encouraging people to ask bad questions that don't show any effort from the asker's side. There is a word for people who answer anything, just to gain rep. It's not a nice word.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a formula for conditional formatting which will return TRUE if at least a word matches.

This is written for cell C2 and it is assumed that it is looking for values in cells F2 to F15.

`=NOT(ISERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&C2," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,2,3}*99,99)),F2:F15,1),F2:F15)))`

Adjust it to suit.

Comment: This site is not a free scripting service. By answering such a bad question you are encouraging people to ask bad questions that don't show any effort from the asker's side. There is a word for people who answer anything, just to gain rep. It's not a nice word.